# Proving union of closures is closure of unions

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Is this okay for proving this subset direction, $\text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B) \supset \text{cl}(A \cup B)$?

Let $x \in \text{cl}(A \cup B)$. Let $U$ be any open set containing $x$. Then $U \cap (A \cup B)=(U \cap A) \cup (U \cap B) \neq \emptyset$.Then $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ or $U \cap B \neq \emptyset$
If $U \cap A \neq \emptyset \implies x \in \text{cl}(A)$. So $x \in  \text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B)$.If $U \cap B \neq \emptyset \implies x \in \text{cl}(B)$. So $x \in  \text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you deduced that $U\cap A$ for some neighborhood of $x$, but not for any neighborhood. (You can say that without loss of generality, $U\cap A\neq\varnothing$ for given $U$, but you can´t say that without loss of generality, $U\cap A\neq\varnothing$ for all $U$).

You can prove that fact by contradiction (spoilers ahead). If $x$ wasn´t in $cl(A)\cup cl(B)$, then you would have $U,V$ neighborhoods of $U$ such that $U\cap A=\varnothing$ and $V\cap B=\varnothing$. Thus, $U\cap V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ with $(U\cap V)\cap(A\cup B)=\varnothing$.

Edit: Some more clarification on why the answer doesn´t work. You can have some neighborhood $U$ with $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and other different neighborhood $V$ such that $V\cap B\neq\emptyset$. That is, for different open sets containing $x$, there can be some that intersect $A$ and others that intersect $B$, but you haven´t yet proved that every neighborhood intersects $A$, or that every neighborhood intersects $B$. You just proved that every neighborhood intersects either $A$ or $B$, which isn´t enough.

You know that every nhood intersects $A$ or $B$:

$\forall U$ neighborhood of $x$, ($U\cap A\neq\varnothing$ or $U\cap B\neq\varnothing$).

And to prove that $x$ is in the closure of $A$ or in the closure of $B$ you need the following:

($\forall U$ neighborhood of $x$ $U\cap A\neq\varnothing$) or ($\forall U$ neighborhood of $x$ $U\cap B\neq\varnothing$).

However, the second statement isn´t implied by the first one, so the proof is incomplete.

Comment: I thought since $U$ was arbitrary, this implies $U$ could be any open set containing $x$.I modified the attempt a bit and really do not see how there is any issue.

Comment: If my try really fails, then I am extremely confused, because this is the way I see every solution attacking these types of problems.

Comment: But $U \cap A \neq \emptyset \implies x \in \text{cl}(A)$ is false, just because $A$ intersects a neighborhood of $x$ doesn´t mean that $x$ is in the closure of $A$. You need that to happen for every nhood of $x$ at the same time. I´ll edit my answer to make that more clear

Comment: Im looking at this proof and seeing how it matches. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151135/the-union-of-two-closure?rq=1  Or now I think you are right after looking at another answer

Comment: It looks like my proof would be ok however if we knew $A,B$ were subsets of a topological space, is this correct?

Comment: In a comment in the answer to that question they also point out that the proof is incomplete. They say "hint: quantors", because they know that every neighborhood intersects either $A$ or $B$ ($\forall x (P\lor Q)$), and they falsely deduce that either every neighborhood intersects $A$ or every neighborhood intersects $B$ ($(\forall x P)\lor (\forall x Q)$). Which is the same problem with the proof here.

Comment: No, you can assume from the context that $A,B$ are subsets of a topological space, the problem is no there

Answer (score 0):

$Cl(X)$ is the $\subseteq$-minimum closed set $Y$ such that $Y\supseteq X.$ Equivalently $Cl(X)$ is the intersection of all closed sets that have $X$ as a subset.

$\bullet \;$So if $Y$ is closed and has $X$ as a subset then $Y\supseteq Cl(X).$

$Cl(A)\cup Cl(B)$ is a closed set that has both $A$ and $B$ as subsets.

$\bullet\;$ So $Cl(A)\cup Cl(B)$ is closed and has $A\cup B$ as a subset, so $Cl(A)\cup Cl(B)\supseteq Cl(A\cup B).$

The reverse inclusion follows at once from $[\,Cl(A\cup B)\supseteq Cl(A)\,]\land [\,Cl(A\cup B)\supseteq Cl(B)\,].$